# Is there a way to kill a process after a certain amount of time after checking the start time of the process in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, process

OS : Ubuntu

Is there a way to use the script to check the start time of a process and then terminate the process after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting the process yourself, consider the `timeout` util.

Example, run `sleep 200d` (sleep for two hundred days), but have `timeout` stop it after three seconds, and have the `time` command show the resources consumed:

```
time timeout 3s sleep 200d
```

Output:

```
real    0m3.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
```